# Hide DTO fields from in swagger model schema but present those fields in response json

Tags: c#, api, rest, swagger-ui

In my API the entity has some fields which are inherited from related objects.

Therefore in `POST` method I **don't** want them to be visible in model schema in **swagger-UI** but I would like them to be displayed **in the response**. Is that possible?

At this moment, as a workaround I use `[ReadOnly(true)]` attribute on the DTO's fields but it's not a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

Create a class like:

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class SwaggerExcludeAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }


    public class SwaggerExcludeFilter : Attribute, ISchemaFilter
    {
        #region ISchemaFilter Members

        public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
        {
            if (schema?.properties == null || type == null)
                return;
            var excludedProperties = type.GetProperties()
                .Where(t =>
                    t.GetCustomAttribute<SwaggerExcludeAttribute>()
                    != null);

            foreach (var excludedProperty in excludedProperties)
            {
                var foundKey = schema.properties.Keys.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Equals(x, excludedProperty.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(foundKey))
                    schema.properties.Remove(excludedProperty.Name);
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

And then in your DTO

```
[SwaggerExclude] //< --decorate the prop you want to exclude from swagger
public string Value1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is probably a good solution but my company would not accept but I will surely give it a try in my own projects.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually resolved this by using 2 different DTOs:

- InputDTO having required fields
- ResponseDTO inheriting from the InputDTO but extending it with the read-only fields.

On controller level the InputDTO is used as method argument, the ResponseDTO is declared in attribute [ResponseType(typeof(ResponseDTO))].

Hope this helps others!